# Acionar dois eventos diferentes com JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Eu gostaria de saber como que faz para acionar diferentes eventos utilizando o mesmo botão. O que eu queria é que, com o próximo clique, ele desse um `jButton1.setText("Créditos");` e voltasse para o `btnGerar.setVisible(true);`

A ideia é que quando eu clicar em "Créditos", sumiria tudo e apareceria apenas o meu nome, e depois que clicasse em voltar(que seria o mesmo botão), ele apareceria os outros menus de volta.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       
    pnBusca.setVisible(false);
    pnOpcao.setVisible(false);
    btnGerar.setVisible(false);
    jButton1.setText("  Voltar  ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

     boolean isVisible;

    if(jButton1.getText().equals.("Créditos")) {

        isVisible = false;
        jButton1.setText("  Voltar  ");
    } else {

        isVisible = true;
        jButton1.setText("Créditos")
    }

    pnBusca.setVisible(isVisible);
    pnOpcao.setVisible(isVisible);
    btnGerar.setVisible(isVisible);
}
```

---

Lembrando que o ideal é sempre resgatar o botão a partir do `ActionEvent`. Simplificando um pouco o código, poderia ficar assim:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    JButton btn = (JButton)evt.getSource();
    boolean isVisible = btn.getText().equals.("Créditos");

    btn.setText(isVisible ? "  Voltar  " : "Créditos");

    pnBusca.setVisible(!isVisible);
    pnOpcao.setVisible(!isVisible);
    btnGerar.setVisible(!isVisible);

}
```